# software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 400)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl, aws-glue, fivetran

Iam trying to add s3 data lake as a destination in Fivetran an ETL tool. For that i have created a role with s3 and glue access, accessed by another aws account user(fivetran). I can able to connect s3 without any issues from Fivetran, but getting the floowing error when connecting to glue. Please help me on this.

Failed Accessing Glue Resources. We encountered the following error : software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: C0JJM26Q8HKX85S7, Extended Request ID: SUhF5M94lRj10YoDbK6L47MIU/8CZyKZXiJtPljjrS47L7Nh7v0hfITjBOwQPharCRPQ4qFI994=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow the Fivetran IAM role to access the S3bucket and glue, ensure your bucket policy has correctly granted permissions.

Also, ensure that the IAM role you've created for Fivetran has the necessary permissions to access both S3 and Glue services.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::FIVETRAN_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:role/FIVETRAN_IAM_ROLE_NAME"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "glue:*",
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```